Adjunction symbol
What are the reasons for the adjunction symbol $F\dashv G$ for a pair of functors $F:C\to D$ and $G:D\to C$? There is no explanation or motivation in the article of Kan where adjunctions are introduced.
The question was previously asked on MathStackExchange without getting an answer.

Clive Newstead has a sensible suggestion at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2693873/87355 : adjoint = "attached to something else", which is what $\dashv$ shows

Kan's paper introduces the symbol $\dashv$ in Definition 3.1.   I don't know where he got it from, but my guess is that it came from "adjoints" in linear algebra.
